# Custom property in RIA service not available on client

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, wcf-ria-services

I have an entity called `StatusUpdates`. There is no self join in it. However i want to include a list of InternalStatusUpdates which is of type `StatusUpdates` (Again i would mention there is no self join in database). So i created a partial class in the same namespace and created a property named InternalStatusUpdates and included `[DataMember]` attribute on it. But it still doesn't appear on the client. This is my partial class to be specific :-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace FMT.Data.Web
{
    public partial class StatusUpdate : EntityObject
    {

         private List<StatusUpdate> _internalListStatusUpdates = new List<StatusUpdate>();
         [DataMember]
         public List<StatusUpdate> InternalListStatusUpdates
         {
             get { return _internalListStatusUpdates; }
             set {
                 _internalListStatusUpdates = value;
                 OnPropertyChanged("InternalListStatusUpdates");
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Interesting thing is if i change `List<StatusUpdate>` to `List<string>` it is available on the client! How do i solve this problem?

I thought because it is entity type i will have to specify `[Include]`. When i did that i get the following error :-

```
Invalid Include specification for member 'StatusUpdate.InternalListStatusUpdates'. Non-projection includes can only be specified on members with the AssociationAttribute applied.
```

Then i went ahead and specified association, so now my property looks like :-

```
private List<StatusUpdate> _internalListStatusUpdates = new List<StatusUpdate>();
     [DataMember]
    [Include]
    [Association("internalUpdates", "StatusUpdatesId", "StatusUpdatesId")]
     public List<StatusUpdate> InternalListStatusUpdates
     {
         get { return _internalListStatusUpdates; }
         set {
             _internalListStatusUpdates = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("InternalListStatusUpdates");
         }
     }
```

where `StatusUpdatesId` is my primary key in `StatusUpdates` Entity and `internalUpdates` is just a arbitary name chosen. Now the build is successfull and the property is available on the client but the data that i populate from server is not available on the client. How do i solve it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: could you share a code snippet with your ria service's body ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The third parameter in AssociationAttribute is the name of the foreign-key property in the list elements. It is important to keep in mind that RIA Services puts entities in their corresponding `EntitySet<T>` and then applies filters on primary key and foreign key instead of using true references to the other objects.

In the given case you will probably have to define a property "ParentUpdatesId" for your list elements and fill that with the primary key of your parent StatusUpdate.

Example:

```
StatusUpdate su = new StatusUpdate { StatusUpdatesId = 123 };
StatusUpdate child1 = new StatusUpdate { StatusUpdatesId = 1001, ParentUpdatesId = 123 };
StatusUpdate child2 = new StatusUpdate { StatusUpdatesId = 1002, ParentUpdatesId = 123 };
su.InternalListStatusUpdates.Add(child1);
su.InternalListStatusUpdates.Add(child2);
```

Your Association would then look like this:

```
[Include]
[Association("internalUpdates", "StatusUpdatesId", "ParentUpdatesId")]
public List<StatusUpdate> InternalListStatusUpdates { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to this page following a search on the error
"non projection includes can only be specified on members with the associationattribute"

Just in case you di likewise...
My problem was that I'd included the include out of habit, but in this particular instance I was joining a many to many table via a link table and was using RIA Services M2M so had specified the particular include elsewhere via a projection.
The error message I was getting was misleading, and removing the Include fixed it.